# Select2 delete button to remove an entire row

Tags: jquery

I have a select2 menu when the user selects a value it will be inserted into a table:

```js
var content = $('#here_table').html();
content += ' <tr role="row" class="filter" >' +
  ' <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">' + '<p >' + userName +
  ' </p>' +
  ' </td>' +
  '<td rowspan="1" colspan="1">' +
  ' <p >' +
  name +
  '</p>' +
  ' </td>' +
  ' <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">' +
  '  <input type="button"  value="Delete" onchange="rChecked()">' +
  ' </td>' +
  '</tr>';
$('#here_table').html(content);
```

I want to create a delete button that only deletes the row, not all of the rows.

This is my code:

```js
$("#ddlUsers").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "http://localhost/-------",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        username: params.term, // search term
        //page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              text: item.FullName,
              id: item.Username
            }
          })
          //pagination: {
          //    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          //}
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
});
```

Comment: use $(this) context can you share your js?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: function rChecked() {
        $('#divDDL').show();
        $('#txtUsers').show();
        $('#removeBtn').show();
    }